# Sorting 2 different sheets with code in same macro

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Goal: Sort Sheet1 Alphabetically, then sort Sheet2 Alphabetically. Code should be in the same macro. Both sorting should be done in column A on respective sheets. Headers are in rows 1 through 6. Data in Sheet1 stretches from col A:AX, Sheet2 ColA:AV

Situation: The sorting codes below work when in separate macros but not when in the same macro. I'd like them to be in the same macro. When they are in the same macro the first sort works and the second one returns:

> Run Time error  1004: Sort ref is not valid. Make Sure that its within
>   the data you want to sort, and the first sort by box isn't the same or
>   blank.

```
Dim wsfull As Worksheet
Dim wscust As Worksheet
Dim wswork As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Lastrow3 As Long
    Set wsfull = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wscust = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = wsfull.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrow3 = wscust.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With wsfull
.Range("A6:AX" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("A6"), Header:=xlYes
End With

With wscust
.Range("A6:AV" & Lastrow3).Sort Key1:=Range("A6"), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: You need the dot in front of `Range("A6")`, otherwise applies to active sheet.

Comment: thanks- should have caught that!